# Закрепить футер внизу при отсутствии прокрутки на странице

Tags: javascript, css

к примуре страница:

https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_examples_material

я заменил футер на

```
<div id="myFooter" class="w3-container w3-theme" style="padding:16px;  bottom: 0; position: fixed;  bottom: 0; text-align: center; width:100%;">
  <p>Footer information goes here</p>
</div>
```

В этом случае футер всегда закреплен внизу окна, если со "style" убрать "position: fixed" то если содержимое меньше окна - футер подскакивает.
Что мне нужно заменить или прописать, чтобы при наличии прокрутки по вертикали футер скролился вместе со страницей, а если содержимое было меньше окна то футер крепился  внизу страницы?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

Если высота футера задана, то можно сделать так. Способ такой себе, но один из самых простых. Ссылку на более интересные способы Вам уже скинули в комментариях к вопросу.

```css
.root {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background: blue;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
Маленький body
</div>
<footer>
Футер внизу
</footer>
```